Locally compact metric space and separation property
Suppose $X$ is a locally compact metric space and $K$ is a compact set and $C$ is a closed set  both in $X$ such that $C\cap K=\varnothing$. Then, there exists open sets $U_1$ of $C$ and $U_2$ of $K$ such that  $U_1\cap U_2= \varnothing$. $U_2$ can be taken to be with compact closure, but $U_1$ cannot be generally to be taken with compact closure.
Question: Can we find a closed neighborhood of $C$ such that its boundary is compact?
Attempt: Since $K$ is compact, and $X$ is locally compact and Hausdorff, there exists a continuous function $f:X\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $K=f^{-1}(0)$ and $C=f^{-1}(1)$. Consider $f^{-1}[1/2,1]$. Then $C\subseteq f^{-1}[1/2,1]$. But I don't see why $f^{-1}[1/2,1]$ has compact bounday.

Consider the case of $X=\mathbb{R}$. Maybe we can let $C$ be an unbounded set and then $U_1$ cannot be with compact closure?

@LittleBear edited

Maybe something is missing in your question. As it is, you can $X$ as the desired closed neighborhood. Its boundary is empty, thus compact.

Yes. Take $N = X \setminus U_2$. We have $U_1 \subset N$, thus $N$ is a closed neighborhood of $C$. The interior of $N$ is $\operatorname{int} N = X \setminus \overline U_2$ and the boundary of $N$ is $\operatorname{bd} N = N \setminus \operatorname{int} N = \overline U_2 \setminus U_2$. Since the closure $\overline U_2$ is compact, also $\operatorname{bd} N$ is compact.
